# Does router have ability of port mirroring?

Tags: router, switch

I want to find how two device exchange packets and what information they send. For that task I decided to buy smart switch with ability of port mirroring. However I will use switch only for that purpose after that it basically useless to me, so I thought maybe I could buy router for that purpose. I even found [how to set up it](http://www.tp-link.us/article/?faqid=528)  And here it got confusing page says router and later on it just states "switch". What's worst my local e-shop perfectly shows switches with port mirroring ability but i can't seem to find description of that kind ability on **TL-ER5120**( that acording to page should have that ability too). Am i missing something? Is it better to buy switch its not that expensive? (I have no ability to test router beside buying it.)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the SME/consumer grade Routers have an integrated switch. So what you see an that TP-Link page is actually the configuration page of a router and it has a subpage where you can configure the "switch-part".
So this basically is a two devices in one thing.